# add UITextField to sprite kit

Tags: uitextfield

hi I've been following some tutorials but this ones for swift 1.2
I'm on Xcode 7.2 think its swift 2.1
he uses a UITextfield with spriteKit
but this line causes an error 
I've googled but can't find any help 
so thought this is the place to help cheers

```
self.view!.addSubview(TextInput!)
```

the whole code is

> import SpriteKit
>
> ```
> class GameScene: SKScene
> {    var TextInput:UITextField?
>
> override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
> {
>
>     let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
>     myLabel.text = ""
>     myLabel.fontSize = 15
>     myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
>
>     self.addChild(myLabel)
>
>     TextInput?.frame = CGRect(x: 200, y: 300, width: 100, height: 40)
>
>     self.view!.addSubview(TextInput!)
>
>     TextInput?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
> }
>
> override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
>    /* Called when a touch begins */
>
>     for touch in touches
>     {
>     let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
>
>     }
> }
>
> override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
>     /* Called before each frame is rendered */
> } }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be initialising your UITextField anywhere.
Try adding this line to didMoveToView before you set the frame of TextInput:

```
self.TextInput = UITextField()
```

Just to note, variable names in Swift should be written in camel case (thisIsCamelCase), so it might be better to rename your variable as **textInput**. I can't actually find this in the Apple documentation right now, but this convention is used in all of Apple's example code, and is stated by various other sources, e.g.

https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide

http://andybargh.com/variables-and-constants-in-swift/#Rules_for_Naming_Variables

Comment: Not very helpful, is it? I tried the same thing. My `TextInput` is initialised. But the view is not added or I cannot see it on an iPhone 5s.